# Open ViewController via code

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on an iOS app that communicates with an Arduino via BLE, uses with multiple ViewControllers which are all set-up via Storyboard. The Views are managed via a TabBarController. At this moment I use an additional Tab to connect/Disconnect to/from the device.

But after the App is useless without the device, I want to have the ViewController (which manages the connecting task) pop up. I've read that I should use Segues, but I don't really know how to call them correctly, and I don't want to call them in every TabViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues are what you should use, but I would suggest learning how storyboards work first. [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1) will be a good resource to get you started. Segues can be used either through code or directly within a storyboard.

Your question is way to general to give a direct answer, as I'd write some 1000 words to get the basis down.

To keep it simple:

- `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: nil)`
- `presentViewController(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
- `navigationController?.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: true)`